# After calling ipython profile create ipython_notebook_config.py was not created

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have installed brand new ipython in a virtual enviorment, after that I tried to create configuration files via: `ipython profile create`, however `ipython_notebook_config.py` was not created, while `ipython_config.py` and `ipython_nbconvert_config.py` were created.

What can I do to create this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that I forgot to install dependencies to ipython notebook (I just did: `pip install ipython`). After you install `ipython[notebook]` or `ipython[all]` (or just install notebook depencies by hand) `ipython profile create` will also create notebook config files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following options to launch ipython notebook without the ipython_notebook_config.py file:

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port 8889 
--ip='*' --no-browser" pyspark
```

or for HortonWorks HDP

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port 8889 --notebook-dir=u'/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/'
--ip='*' --no-browser" pyspark
```